# Como manipular um Objecto Json antes de retornar na API

Tags: java, spring-mvc, gson, json

Olá

estou com este método no meu controller:

```
@GetMapping(value="/{id}/perfil", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String carregarPerfilUsuario(@PathVariable("id") Long id, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
     
    obj.put("usuario", ur.findWhereId(id));
    obj.put("postagem", pr.findAllWhereUserId(id));
    
    return gson.toJson(obj);

}
```

estou usando `gson` para transformar um objeto em json e `JsonOBJECT` para criar um obj que será retornado no final:

```
private static final Gson gson = new Gson();
private static final JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
```

porem não sei porque ao converter meus dados ele insere atributos indesejados na minha api:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Map** e **MyArrayList**, eu queria que não vinhe-se esses atributos quando eu convertesse, como eu consigo?

O resultado que busco, é semelhante a imagem, apenas gostaria que não tivesse estes atributos que comentei em negrito na pergunta.

Comment: Veja se utilizar o JsonObject do próprio GSON, em vez do JSONObject, resolve seu problema.

Comment: Está usando a classe certa (`JsonObject`)? Tentei reproduzir aqui mas não encontrei o método `put` nessa classe :(

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Os métodos que você está utilizando sugerem que você tem um Map (método put) e um ArrayList (método findAll), daí seu map e seu myArrayList.

O correto a se fazer é ter um POJO que represente o objeto a ser retornado pela sua API, e populá-lo com os dados de usuário e postagem.

Por exemplo:

```
public class PostagemDTO {

   private Usuario usuario;
   private List<Postagem> postagens;

   // getters e setters

}
```

Assim sua API retornará o resultado desejado.

Espero que ajude!

Comment: Oi Tomaz! Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Concordo com o seu ponto de vista em relação a construir uma classe para servir de retorno para o método, ao invés de String, mas essa não foi a pergunta dele.
Ele questiona o funcionamento do GSON e suas classes.
Novamente, concordo contigo sobre a implementação de um modo geral. Inclusive, você pode usar isso como complemento a uma resposta que responda exatamente o perguntado! :)

Comment: Olá, acho que não fui claro então... O resultado que ele está buscando não precisa das classes internas do GSON, basta criar e popular o POJO conforme eu mostrei, e usar o método .toJson Mas claro que o Spring faz isso sozinho se ele retornar o POJO direto no controle sim. Valeu!